# SDL2 snake takes a U turn on itself. Collision problem

Tags: c++, enums, 2d, sdl-2

let this arrow be the snake heading to right direction while game is running:

---->

**the problem is** if i press up-key and manage to press left-key very quickly after that , then the snake take this u-turn and hit itself:

---->-<

game over.

looks like the snake is skipping one of the iterations of the game and doesn't move at all.

it means on one iteration of game loop the variable dir sets it's value to direction_up but switch statement doesn't execute.
so theres a point where "dir = direction_up" but snake is really heading right-direction.

**i want to** prevent the snake from taking u-turn.
the snake should move in one direction on each frame(each iteration of game loop).

i want turn keypresses to be ignored if snake hasn't moved at least 1 tile since previous turn?

---

this enum is outside of main loop:

```
enum directions
{
    direction_default,
    direction_down,
    direction_left,
    direction_right,
    direction_up,
    direction_total
};
```

handling event inside game loop:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
{
    //poll for currently pending events
    if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {quit = 1;}
    if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN && dir != direction_up)
            dir = direction_down;
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP && dir != direction_down)
            dir = direction_up;
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT && dir != direction_right)
            dir = direction_left;
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT && dir != direction_left)
            dir = direction_right;
    }
}
```

this switch statement for moving:

```
switch(dir)
{
    //check which direction snake is moving
    case direction_down:
        head.y += 10;
        break;
    case direction_up:
        head.y -= 10;
        break;
    case direction_left:
        head.x -= 10;
        break;
    case direction_right:
        head.x += 10;
        break;
}
```

Comment: What do you think should happen (i.e. what do you want to be happening)?

Comment: ***the snake ignores the second conditional statement and turns on itself and collides with itself.*** I don't think it ignores anything. The problem is the snake did not move at all before changing directions when 2 buttons are pressed quickly. Maybe you want to change `while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))` to `if(SDL_PollEvent(&e))` but this may create other problems because of your `SDL_Delay(30);` you could keep another variable that retains the `last_directon_moved`  (set in your switch/ case) and use that as a condition in your `if ( cond1 && cond2)` statements

Comment: @drescherjm 
actually both of these solutions worked .thank you so much.
and if loop caused no problem with SDL_Delay()

Comment: Great. I am busy at the day job as a c++ software engineer. If the question is still open later (currently has 2 out of 3 close votes) I can try writing a solution.

Comment: @drescherjm
that would be great.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @no_hope what you edited in is too vague to be desired behaviour. If i press described key combination, what you want to be happening? Should last press be ignored as invalid move and snake should move up? Should both be discarded? Should snake teleport to 0 location so it isn't colliding with itself? All that variants fit into "not colliding with itself", and answer to that question should hint at how one could do it.

Comment: @keltar
ok, i tried to make it better.

Comment: here is the final project with no textures : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z6Puci8lGc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving any problem starts with clear and precise description of desired behaviour. How about this: "i want turn keypresses to be ignored if snake hasn't moved at least 1 tile since previous turn"? When stated that way, it should be obvious how to implement it.

You could accumulate distance your snake travelled without changing its direction, e.g.:

```
int moved_since_last_turn = 0;

// ...
while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
{
    //poll for currently pending events
    if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {quit = 1;}
    if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if(moved_since_last_turn == 0) { continue; }
        // set new direction to ndir and compare it with old direction later
        int ndir = dir;
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN && dir != direction_up)
            ndir = direction_down;
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP && dir != direction_down)
            ndir = direction_up;
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT && dir != direction_right)
            ndir = direction_left;
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT && dir != direction_left)
            ndir = direction_right;

        if(dir != ndir)
        {
            // direction changed, reset move counter
            dir = ndir;
            moved_since_last_turn = 0;
        }
    }
}

// ...

moved_since_last_turn += 1;
switch(dir)
{
    //check which direction snake is moving
    // ...
}
```

As a side note, I'd suggest untying your logic from frame rate. Oftentimes you need to redraw in much higher rate than your logic step, e.g. when OS tells you your previous image is no longer valid and you have to redraw, or when you have some animation and/or effects that you need to redraw at righer rate while snake's logic remains fixed step, intedepndent on how often you draw. It also simplifies things quite a bit.